# Set of complex values of a non-constant entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: If f(z) is a non-constant entire function, what can the set A = {|f(z)| : z ∈ ℂ} be? Give an example for each possible case (there are two cases).

I know that the range of an entire non-constant function is dense in ℂ, but the only two cases I can think of is A = 0 and A = c (some constant). I don't know if I'm on the right track, and any help with interpreting the question is welcome.

Comment: Hi, welcome to mathSE. I encourage you to have a look at [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to properly typeset math in your question!

Answer (score 2):

By [Picard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem#:%7E:text=The%20theorems,-Plot%20of%20the&text=Little%20Picard%20Theorem%3A%20If%20a,plane%20minus%20a%20single%20point.) any non-constant entire function assumes the whole values on the complex plane or with one exception. The example for the first case is $f(z)=z$. For the second case, take $f(z)=e^z$. So for your question, $A=[0,\infty)$ or $A=(0,\infty).$

Answer (score 1):

Hers is an answer that avoids Picard's Theorem. Since $|f(z)|$ is a continuous function its range is an interval contained in $[0, \infty)$. If the lower end point is a number $a >0$ then $|f(z)| \geq a$ for all $z$ and this contradicts the fact you alredy know that the range of $f$ is dense. Similarly you get a contradiction if the right end point of the interval is finite. Hence the range is $(0,\infty)$ or $[0, \infty)$.